# Contains находит цифры, но не находит слово

Tags: java

```
if(nextLine.contains("Слово")){
     Sysyem.out.println(nextLine);
}
```

При поиске цифры в строке, всё хорошо работает, подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Comment: покажите `nextLine`

Comment: nextLine это строка? А может быть буквы из разных языков?

Comment: Возможно проблема в кодировках, делайте брекпоинт и смотрите содержимое

Answer (score 1):

Как говорил Шерлок Холмс:

*"Отбросьте всё невозможное, то, что останется, и будет ответом".*

---

Некоторые буквы ("С", "о", "о") - из другого алфавита.

```
"С" != "C"
```

Comment: В принципе логично.